# Custom key serdes per binding in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm trying to understand how to use a different key serializer/deserializer in Spring Cloud Stream. I've found the way to specify global serdes but I don't understand how to specify different serdes per binding, in order to allow different key types (Integer, Strings, etc). 
For example the following config specifies global key serdes using property `spring.kafka.consumer.keyDeserializer` and `spring.kafka.producer.keySerializer`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: user                    
          group: my-group
        output:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: user     
          producer:
            partition-count: 2      
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: default:9092
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://default:8081
  kafka:
    consumer:
      keyDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      keySerializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

I'm able to consume and produce message key using the following code snippets:

```
// Consumer
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void handle(@Payload UserValue user, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + user + " with key: " + key + " and headers: " + headers);
    }

// Producer
UserValue user = UserValue.newBuilder().setName("Alessandro").setSurname("Dionisi").build();
        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(user).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "1").build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via `configuration` property

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<bindingName>.consumer.configuration.<whatever-kafka-property-name>=. . .`

See more info [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties)